# Subproccess exits when parent python script stopped by systemd

Tags: subprocess, systemd, python-3.7

I am new to python and wanted to get familiar, so I created a python script that uses Popen from subprocess to execute a bash script. The bash script sets up an environment for, and executes a c++ program to run in the background.

The intended use is to run the python script as a service that watches for the C++ process, and if the C++ process exits, run the bash startup script again.

Everything runs as intended if I start the python script from the command line (`./proc_watchdog.py`), and then ctr+c, the C++ process will continue running.

If I then execute the the python script using systemd, `systemd start pythonscript.service` and then stop it `systemd stop pythonscript.service`, the C++ program exits.

The .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=RustDedicated watchdog service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=scriptuser
ExecStart=/path/to/C++_Prog_Dir/proc_watchdog.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess as sp
import os
import psutil
import time

backgroundProc = "Procname"

def processWatchdog():
   waitCount = 0;

   while True:
      procList = []

      for proc in psutil.process_iter():
         procList.append(proc.as_dict(attrs=['name']))

      found = 0
      for pname in procList:
         if backgroundProc == pname['name']:
            print("Process running")
            found = 1

      if found == 0:
         print("Process not found...")
         waitCount += 1
         if waitCount == 3:
            p = sp.Popen(["/path/to/C++_Prog_Dir/start.sh"])
            print("Restarting")
            p.wait()
            waitCount = 0
            print("Restarted")

      time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   processWatchdog()
```

Bash script example:

```
#!/bin/bash

./c++_process &>> /dev/null &

exit 0
```

Can anyone help me understand why the python script would behave differently for each of the ways it gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

Do supervision properly have the parent wait on the child. When the child exits, restart it. This is what DJB's daemontools does.

Change your script from:

```
./c++_process &>> /dev/null &
```

to:

```
exec ./c++_process &>> /dev/null
```

Then your watch dog will be alerted immediately when `p.wait()` returns that it has to restart the program as it had exited. With that your watch dog can be reduced to:

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

def processWatchdog():

   while True:
       p = sp.Popen(["/path/to/C++_Prog_Dir/start.sh"])
       p.wait()

       time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   processWatchdog()
```

Which simply restarts the program with a 2 second delay.

Comment: I understand what youre saying, but my intent is to basically have the process watcher run independently from the c++ program. Basically python watches to make sure the C++ process is running (the psutil components finds the process), and if its not found, run the starter script using Popen and fork so that when/if systemd stops or restarts the python loop, it as the parent process doesnt kill the c++ program, which is what my code in the original post was doing.

Comment: So the issue is how to let the program exit-when-finished when the service is stopped. Doing this require more understanding of systemd than I have. I personally think what you are attempting is against proper design.

Answer (score 0):

service parameter "KillMode" default value is "contorl-group", means all remaining processes in the control group of this unit will be killed

"process" or "none" I used and works well

Comment: Hey, could you update this answer to have some documentation to help others understand what you are looking at?